# How to produce ionizing radiation without radioactive substance?

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, radioactivity, gamma-rays

I think ionizing radiation caused by ray or particles.
My professor told me:"without radioactive substance,with only commercial products,it's possible to produce ionizing radiation."

Can anyone give me some thoughts about the methodology.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode-ray_tube, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_tube

Comment: Ultraviolet light with wavelength less than ~120 nm is also ionising radiation.

Comment: and particle accelerators too

Comment: oh, and cosmic radiation.

Comment: Technically, bananas are commercial products... and yet, they are often considered in popular science as sources of ionizing radiation: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_equivalent_dose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultraviolet light is capable of ionizing a variety of substances; this effect is quite strong and allows UV to be used to disinfect drinking water and kill bacteria as well as giving you a sunburn.